# Two questions about assembly

Tags: assembly

1. What mean name:.space 2^32
   That means i reserve space equal too 2 to the power 32?
2. When i divide number by 16 how to get remainder?
   I need to change number from Dec to Hex and i think about that:

   - Divide by 16
   - Check if reaminder value>9
   - If it is i will change value to text from {A-F}
   - Make a loop

Comment: Please do not ask two questions in one post. Also, tag your question with the appropriate architecture and try to give sensible title.

Comment: What has this to do with assembly? This is algorithms, and decimal to hex is one you can find anywhere.

Comment: So is your question how to divide a number to get the quotient and the remainder? Or is it how to output a text representation of a number you have in a register?

Comment: how to divide a number to get the quotient and the remainder

Comment: What assembly language? 68000? x86? ARM? You could perhaps do a Google search on "divide instruction for XXXX", where you replace XXXX with the name of the processor you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Remainder of a division by a power of 2 is as simple as AND-ing your number with the divisor minus one, so for your divisor of 16 you need to AND with 15.  The result of the AND operation is your remainder.

Similarly, if you shift right 4 bits (2^4 = 16) you will get the quotient of that same division.

To convert to hex, just put the above in a loop and you can get the remainder for numbers of any byte size, one nibble at a time that you then need to convert to ASCII hex representation (from right to left).

*(Again, this method works only for divisors which are powers of 2 as in your specific case.)*

To change the nibble from binary (0 to 15) to ASCII hex digit, you can also use the following shortcut but only if your processor supports a DAA (Decimal Addition Adjust) operation:

```
            add       #$90
            daa
            adc       #$40
            daa
```

*(The exact instructions will of course depend on your specific assembly language.)*

Answer (score 0):

Michael, this is the answer for your second question. What you need is a little complicated. Next code does the job and it's fully commented to help you understand. You didn't specify what kind of assembler, so I'm using 8086 Intel syntax. Just copy-paste it in EMU8086 and run it. The program takes a number from AX, converts it to hex and displays it. The algorithm is yours : succesive divisions by 16, every remainder (in the range 0..15) is converted to hex digit, then it's displayed. The funny thing about this algorithm is that digits are extracted in reverse order, so it's necessary to reverse them again to get them straight, that's why the succesive remainders are stored in stack (because things in stack get reversed when poped out) :

```
.stack 100h
.data
hex_char db ?,'$' ;HEX CHARACTERS TO DISPLAY.
.code      
;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax,@data
  mov  ds,ax

  mov  ax, 30922  ;ANY NUMBER TO CONVERT.
  call number2hex                

;FINISH PROGRAM.
  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h     

;-------------------------------------
;THIS PROC CONVERTS AX INTO HEX AND DISPLAYS RESULT.
;ALGORITHM : DIVIDE AX BY 16, CONVERT REMAINDER INTO 
;HEX (0..9,A..F), REPEAT UNTIL QUOTIENT == 0. DIGITS 
;EXTRACTED ARE BEEN PRESERVED IN STACK BECAUSE THEY
;HAVE TO BE DISPLAYED IN REVERSE ORDER.
;REMAINDER IS ALWAYS LESS THAN 16.

proc number2hex               

;PHASE 1 : EXTRACT ALL DIGITS INSERTING THEM IN STACK.

  mov  bx, 16  ;DIVIDE NUMBER BY 16. 
  mov  cx, 0   ;COUNTER FOR DIGITS. NECESSARY LATER.
extracting:         
  mov  dx, 0  ;CLEAR DX BECAUSE DIV DIVIDES DX:AX / BX.
  div  bx     ;DX:AX / BX. RESULT: AX=QUOTIENT, DX=REMAINDER.
  cmp  ax, 0  ;IF ( QUOTIENT==0 ) PROCESS IS OVER.
  je   last_digit
  push dx  ;PRESERVE DIGIT FOR LATER CONVERSION.
  inc  cx  ;COUNT THIS DIGIT.
  jmp  extracting  ;REPEAT PROCESS.

;WHEN PROCESS IS OVER REMAINDER STILL HOLDS LAST DIGIT.
last_digit:
  push dx  ;PRESERVE DIGIT FOR LATER CONVERSION.
  inc  cx  ;COUNT THIS DIGIT.

;PHASE 2 : EXTRACT DIGITS FROM STACK IN REVERSE ORDER
;CONVERTING THEM TO HEX AND DISPLAY THEM.       

converting:
  pop  dx  ;GET DIGIT FROM STACK.
  call convert_hex  ;CONVERT DL INTO HEX.
  call display_hex  ;DISPLAY DL.
  loop converting   ;CX-1. IF ( CX > 0 ) GOTO CONVERTING.

  ret
endp  

;-------------------------------------
;GETS THE VALUE IN "DL" AND REPLACES IT
;BY THE CORRESPONDING HEX VALUE.

proc convert_hex
  cmp  dl, 10
  jb   its_a_number  ;IF ( DL < 10 ) IT'S A NUMBER.
;IF NO JUMP IT'S A LETTER.
  add  dl, 55  ;CONVERT 10..15 TO 'A'..'F'.
  jmp  end_convert  ;SKIP "ITS_A_NUMBER".
its_a_number: 
  add  dl, 48  ;CONVERT 0..9 TO '0'..'9'.
end_convert:
  ret
endp

;-------------------------------------
;GET HEX DIGIT IN "DL", TRANSFER VALUE
;TO "HEX_CHAR", DISPLAY "HEX_CHAR".

proc display_hex
  mov  hex_char, dl
  mov  dx, offset hex_char
  mov  ah, 9
  int  21h
  ret
endp
```

Notice sometimes DX is used and other times it's DL. This is because stack requieres two bytes (DX), but remainder is always 8 bits long (DL), because dividing by 16 throws a remainder less than 16 (0..15).